How to combine intention-to-treatment randomization with block randomized experimental designs for within-differences in Power Analysis
I want to calculate the power for my experiment. Within multiple blocks of similarities (e.g., same gender, same pre-treatment outcome), respondents get the opportunity to take part in a treatment. As only half of them (within each block) get offered the treatment, I have an intention-to-treat design and want to use IV (instrumental variables) to estimate LATE (local average treatment effects) of this binary treatment (this is to say, on the compliers). However, given my block design (and likely, unequal sizes of n within blocks), I struggle to perform a power analysis for this blocked-IV design.
I am a) interested in the within-person difference in my outcome variable. Therefore, I will use it as a pre-treatment blocking variable, just more coarse than it actually is. This outcome variable is measured on a 6-point Likert scale and blocked in high/low (plus there are other factors like age to block for).  (This outcome is perceived confidence in programs like the one offered to some participants.)
b) Moreover, the individual shift in the outcome (from a) is tested on it's influence for another outcome, outcome2. Outcome 2 is only measured at the end of the study, no prior values. (This is the health outcome after participation/no participation.)
Given this second outcome, in b), which is not blocked for, how can I perform a power analysis for this?
I can use R, or G power for my analysis.
